# Firebase[Storage]: Implementing Firebase for Native Java Application

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage

Is it possible to Implement the Firebase Storage for Native Java Application because from the previous version of Firebase there's [firebase-client-jvm-2.5.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.firebase/firebase-client-jvm/2.5.2) JVM Client. I want to call the Upload Task and StorageReference from the newer version.. seems it's not supported?